# What is the difference between 'somebody who doing' and 'somebody who be doing'?

Tags: difference, clauses

I am constructing some sentences.

> She is now the one who steering the company Hairson.

> She is now the one who is steering the company Hairson.

I find it both correct to use either 'somebody who is doing' or 'somebody who doing'. But I want to know is any difference between them.

Comment: *I'm the user writing this* and *I'm the user **who is** writing this* are both syntactically fine, and mean exactly the same (it's just a stylistic choice whether to include the two extra highlighted words). But *I'm the user **who** writing this* is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is grammatically wrong, only the second one is correct:

> She is now the one who is steering the [Hairson] company.

It cannot be "somebody who doing", you have to specify "is".

"the company Harison" also has to be changed here by swapping the words.

Comment: Also 'the company Hairson' might need correcting maybe?

Comment: is it correct now? @MichaelHarvey or do I say "the company named Hairson"

Comment: 'The Hairson company' is OK.